# JVisualVM problem with monitoring JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, monitoring, jvisualvm

I want to monitor my application running inside JBoss version 3.2.5 using JVisualVM. I have installed my app to run ass windows serivce. JVisualVM sees my application but i can't see neither thread dump or heap dump. Profiling is not possible either. I get an error dialog with an error icon but with no text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the same user is running JVisualVM, and JBoss.

Also, I've noticed that you can not profile remote connections.  So if possible, make sure to run JVisualVM on the same machine.

If you can't run JVisualVM on the same machine, I've read that [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/profiler.html) has remote profiling support.  But I've never personally used it.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that your JBoss is running Java 5; Java 6 is required for the advanced profiling and monitoring functionality.  I have just recently tested this myself (with the Sun Java 5 JVM, not JBoss).

[Feature matrix for JVisualVM http://www.postimage.org/Pq3fZyJ-082d768361c91340a8014cf7ec893896.png](http://www.postimage.org/Pq3fZyJ-082d768361c91340a8014cf7ec893896.png).